# Having trouble having a "done" button appear, that closes a datePickerView from UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datepicker, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField`, that is currently showing the `DatePickerView` correctly. I have tried looking around on how to add a done button, but I can't find a way for it to work or register to close the `DatePicker`.

Here's the function that shows the `DatePicker` when someone clicks on the `UITextField`:

```
@IBAction func selectDate(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView

    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}
```

and here's a function that tracks any changes and displays it inside the `UITextField`

```
func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none

    birthday.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

}
```

How would I add a button to this specific code that closes `DatePicker`?

Comment: And how would I dismiss the datePicker (or keyboard for example) if user touches anywhere in the viewController, aside for the textField and keyboardPicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 30))

let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: “Done”, style: .Done, target: self, action: Selector(“doneButtonAction”))

var buttons = [UIBarButtonItem]()
buttons.append(space)
buttons.append(doneButton)
toolbar.setItems(buttons, animated: false)
toolbar.sizeToFit()


self.datePickerView.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}

func doneButtonAction(){
self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One other way is that in `datePickerValueChanged` event first dismiss keyboard and then hide your `UIDatePicker`.

```
func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none

        birthday.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

       self.view.endEditing(true) // Hide keyboard

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
 }
```

By using this you do not need any done button.
It will resign your textField or textView by tapping outside of it.
**Note**: It will not affect on scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

add following two actions and add code in viewDidLoad function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView!.datePickerMode = .Date
        txtxt.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView!.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(self.view.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(44)))
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Bordered, target: self, action:"ShowSelectedDate")

        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        toolBar.items = [space, doneBtn]
        txtxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
 func ShowSelectedDate(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        txtxt.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }
```